# Pass "dd-MMM-yyyy" to datetime by post method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How Can I pass `"dd-MMM-yyyy"` Date format to `DateTime` by Post method?

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? SomeDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: is this possible dd-MMM-YYYY? check that may be MM

Comment: @shas, No It's MMM, two different thing `dd-MMM-yyyy` and `dd-MM-YYYY`

Comment: above way not working or what?

Comment: You can't unless your create a custom ModelBinder that parses the value to a valid `DateTime` using your servers culture settings.

Answer (score 0):

Format date from model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? SomeDate { get; set; }
```

You can format date in View file by following way

```
<span>@Convert.ToDateTime(SomeDate).ToString("MMM-yyyy")</span>
```

Comment: Does this helpful?